# python -m django --version doesn't show version even if it's installed

Tags: python, django, macos

I'm on MacOS

Why does following command doesn't show django? Is there any inherent problem with python/django installation?

```
python -m django --version

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3: No module named django
```

I think django is installed as I can see it from

```
pip freeze | grep Django
Django==1.11.20
```

and

```
django-admin.py version
1.11.20
```

Comment: did you activate the virtual environment?

Comment: you may have two Pythons installed and pip may install modules for other Python then you use to check `-m django --version`. You can check `pip -V` and `python -V` or you can use `python -m pip install django`

Comment: Yes you are right, I've two versions installed which explains this anomaly.

Comment: use pip freeze to get all the packages along with versions